# open a folder in particular view office 365 / SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, 2016

I want to open a folder inside document library in a particular view

for example, assume that I have a folder called "Projects" and I want to open it in "Admin" view, which is public

I tried

```
www.sitename.com/sites/SO/Shared Documents/Projects/Admin.aspx
```

and it  obviously didn't  work.

Is there a way to make folders open in a particular view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form your url like this:

```
https://webapp.domain.com/sites/sitecoll/Shared Documents/Admin.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/sitecoll/Shared Documents/Projects/Folder2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below URL :

```
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Atest/Shared Documents/Forms/Admin.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/Atest/Shared Documents/Projects
```

please replace 
**xxxx.sharepoint.com** to your real domain and **Atest** to your site name